# How do Protoss eat or breathe?

Tags: starcraft

The Protoss are depicted as having neither nostrils or a mouth (unless this was retconned and no one told me). This might sound freaky and alien at first but when one stops to think about it- without these orifices shouldn't they have starved/suffocated a long time ago?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Questions about the Protoss' eating habits were addressed in a [Q&A with the game's makers](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/StarCraft_II_Q%26A_batches/19).

> ***Q. What do the protoss eat? (where do they get energy and mass?)***
>
> ***A.*** **Protoss gain nutrition from sunlight, or at a pinch, moonlight (which
>   is just reflected sunlight anyway) by absorbing through their skins.**
>   They can go for extended periods without absorbing sunlight. **What
>   little moisture they need is also absorbed through their skin.**

This is backed up by the Starcraft novel [Firstborn](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/StarCraft:_The_Dark_Templar_Saga:_Firstborn) which states that the Protoss covert light into energy, presumably through some form of photosynthesis.

> *Jake’s footsteps slowed as they approached the omhara’s lair. He turned to Savassan, his eyes wide, and Savassan sent a message of reassurance. Not for the first time, **Jake thought about the ways other creatures obtained sustenance. For the protoss it was easy — the White Circle of night and the Golden Orb of day showed their favor to the protoss and nourished them. Their light, and that of their children, the smaller glittering sky-gems that appeared at night, was all
>   the protoss needed to flourish.***

And in the official [StarCraft Field Manual](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/StarCraft_Field_Manual).

> *The face features two glowing eyes but no mouth, nose, or ears—in fact
>   Protoss have no orifices whatsoever. **Most nutritional intake or waste
>   excretion occurs at a molecular level, passing directly through
>   semipermeable skin that's remarkably complex in its cellular
>   structure. The rough, scaly epidermis absorbs light for sustenance
>   (even if reflected, such as moonlight) and also absorbs and excretes
>   moisture. Smell and sound are sensed through the skin as well.***

Comment: boo iwas typing that up

Comment: @Himarm - Too slow, G.I. Joe.

Comment: Yeah but didn't the SC1 manual say they used to be hunters? And this still doesn't explain how they breath (shouldn't they need to do both?).

Comment: @Nu'Daq That might be a good point about being hunters. Is it hunting if you don't eat? The breathing part could be addressed by the end of the novel blockquote: "...was all the Protoss needed to flourish". Not knowing how Protoss biology works, they may *not* need to breathe.

Comment: Since Oxygen is only needed for the end goal of the digestive cycle (burning the materials made via digestion), I can see why they wouldn't need to do it. Also, hunters don't necessarily *eat* prey, though that was clearly the intent in the writing.

Comment: @Axelrod: Is it really the intent that it's for eating, or for materials such as furs, bones, etc?

Comment: @Ellesedil That's a good point. You could hunt for materials, rather than for sustenance.

Comment: @Nu'Daq  its specifically stated they hunted for skins not food in later works

Comment: Also if they can absorb water through their skin, they already have access to oxygen. And if they need more seems logical the skin can also absorb oxygen out of the air. But we know they need little, since they can function on airless planets, hostile planets, humans at least need suits with oxygen to survive

Comment: The Protoss have not evolved into what they are now, there species was created perfect.

Comment: @Axelrod: you're assuming the Protoss have human-like biology and requirements. Being aliens, they don't necessarily need oxygen for their digestive cycle. Or have any form of digestion whatsoever, for that matter, except for a photosynthesis-like digestion of sunlight. "The thing about aliens is: they are alien."

Comment: I'm probably going to regret bringing this up, but wouldn't having "no orifices whatsoever" get in the way of reproduction?

Comment: @Nu'Daq - When a mummy and daddy protoss love each other very much, they have a special hug they can do where they **share DNA with a scientist and make babby in a test tube**. Historically the female would bear the young (hence boobs and wide hips) but in the modern era they lack the ability to do so.

Comment: @Valorum Ha ha so funny I forgot to laugh- but seriously, 'no orifices whatsoever' shouldn't complicate things?

Comment: @Nu'Daq - Once you've got "semipermeable skin", pretty much everything else is optional or non-essential.